# Ошибка синтаксиса JOIN

Tags: sql, access, inner-join

Access выдает ошибку при запуске запроса, не понимаю что не так. есть таблица `tTransactions`, в ней столбцы:

- `iConstituentID`
- `cAmount`
- `iResponseID`
- `dDate`

Задача следующая - выбрать все последние записи по каждому человеку (`iConstituentID`) с `iResponseID` равным `34` - дата в этой выборке будет `Datereact`.

Дальше выбрать все последние записи по каждому человеку с `iResponseID` не равным 34 или 54, при том что `dDate` должна быть меньше `Datereact`  - дата в этой выборке будет  `Datedonationbeforereact`. В итоге получить выборку людей с разницей между датами `Datereact` и `Datedonationbeforereact`.

```
SELECT m. iConstituentID
     , DiffDate( (m.Datedonationbeforereact), (t.Datereact) )     
FROM (
    (   
       SELECT tTransaction.iConstituentID
            , tTransaction.dDate AS Datereact
            , tTransaction.iResponseID
            , tTransaction.cAmount    
       FROM tTransaction    
       WHERE ((tTransaction.iResponseID)=34) 
             AND ((tTransaction.cAmount)>0)
    )  AS t    
    INNER JOIN (    
        SELECT tTransaction.iConstituentID
             , Max(tTransaction.dDate) AS Datedonationbeforereact
             , tTransaction.iResponseID
             , tTransaction.cAmount    
        FROM tTransaction     
        WHERE (
            (  (tTransaction.iResponseID)<>34 
               AND (tTransaction.iResponseID)<>54) 
               AND  (  (tTransaction.cAmount)>0))    
            )     
    AS m ON t.iConstituentID = m.iConstituentID

WHERE ((m.Datedonationbeforereact)<(t.Datereact));
```

Comment: diffdate - это ваша функция?
Если вы имели в виду datediff, то она имеет 3 обязательных параметра.

Comment: у вас там кажется скобок лишних есть. это аксесс их так рассталвяет что ли?

Answer (score 0):

Не хватает закрывающей скобки перед последним `WHERE` или удалить открывающую после первого `FROM`